# Django Model form with read only properties

Tags: python, django, forms

first of all let me explain the scenario: I'm working in a CRUD with Django 1.8.7, Python 2.7 and bootstrap as frontend. In the List of this CRUD when the user pressed the Add button a modal will open with a combo for the user to select what kind of item he wants to create. The user selects the option and the next form is loaded dynamically. So far it is working great. My problem is: the combo the user selected while in the list is one of the fields of this form and this field cannot be changed. It must be in the form just as text.

Examples:

Current form:

[image: Current form]

What the form should be when the Url is : domain.com/adm/products/add?category_id=2

[image]

When the category_id is passed on the querystring I don't want to allow the user to edit this value.

My question is: how can I achieve this? I'm using the CreateView for the view and ModelForm for the form.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: It is unclear what your question is

Comment: Please clarify the following: "The user selects the option" .. is this the option you are trying to make readonly ?.  Also does this quoted text accurate  " .. and the next form is loaded dynamically" or should it be instead "... and the next form ELEMENT is loaded dynamically".   Let me take a wild guess, - Do you mean the "form element value" that is dynamically loaded based on the initial selection the user made in the modal box, should be really presented as an informational text output ?

Comment: @BobbyC  I have updated the question with images showing what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. First you have to create a custom widget that will render the way you want. In my case the original widget was a combo (select), so I found this widget:

```
class ReadOnlySelect(Select):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        display = "None"
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if utf8_encode(option_value) == utf8_encode(value):
                display = option_label
        output = format_html('<p>%s</p><input type="hidden" value="%s"  %s> ' % (display, value, flatatt(final_attrs)))
        return mark_safe(output)
```

Second step you have to set the default value for the field, in the CreateView overwriting the get_initial method:

```
def get_initial(self):        
    category = None        
    if self.request.method == "GET" :
        # this method sets the initial value for the fields               
        try:
            category = Category.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('category_id'))
        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_(u"Destination not found."))

    return {'category': category}
```

Third step you set the widget to be used in the field:

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['category','title' ]
        widgets = {
            'category': ReadOnlySelect(),
        }
```

Then when django loads the form the field will appear as a text followed by a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the field again just before meta.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    inp_type = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
    class meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['id']
```

Comment: seems this solution is incomplete, what do you do then with `inp_type`?